# Need Help combining two Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, match

I need to combine these two regular expressions.

First one:

```
\)\p{Any}*?\(
```

This will be used to match all information between ) and (

Second Regex:

```
[^/.;\p{L&}\p{Nd}-]+
```

This will be used to match specific "invalid characters" in a program.

I need these to function together, so that it only matches invalid characters that are found between ) and (

Example:

> ```
> 111111111(11111#1111)1111
> 11111111$1111111111111111
> 1111.;/-1111111(1111&111)
> 1111111111$11111111111111
> 1111111(11111111$1111)111
> 111111111111$111111111111
> ```

I need the result of the combined regex to only match the three $ on the 2nd, 4th, and 6th line.

Definition of "invalid characters"- all non-alphanumerics, except for .;/-

I am new to all of this and I'm trying my best. This is a one-time thing for me. I really need some help. I posted this question before and no one gave me any input, they just kept critiquing my post and asking me more questions. Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Oh, and ill be using the regex in EditPad, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Try [this expression](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%29%5b%5e%28%5d*%3f%29%5b%5e%28%2f.%3b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bNd%7d-%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%28%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%28%7c%24%29%29&i=111111111%2811111%231111%291111%0d%0a11111111%241111111111111111%0d%0a1111.%3b%2f-1111111%281111%26111%29%0d%0a1111111111%2411111111111111%0d%0a1111111%2811111111%241111%29111%0d%0a111111111111%24111111111111).

Comment: OH! Its so close! Its matching spaces, how do i keep it from doing that? Thank you SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Add `\s` to the character class: `(?<=\)[^(]*?)[^\s(/.;\p{L}\p{Nd}-]+(?=[^(]*(?:\(|$))`

Comment: You, Sir, are my HERO! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the regex based on variable-width lookarounds (since EditPad supports infinite-width lookbehinds):

```
(?<=\)[^(]*?)[^\s(/.;\p{L}\p{Nd}-]+(?=[^(]*(?:\(|$))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%29%5B%5E%28%5D*%3F%29%5B%5E%5Cs%28%2F.%3B%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BNd%7D-%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%28%5D*%28%3F%3A%5C%28%7C%24%29%29&i=111111111%2811111%231111%291111%0D%0A11111111%241111111111111111%0D%0A1111.%3B%2F-1111111%281111%26111%29%0D%0A1111111111%2411111111111111%0D%0A1111111%2811111111%241111%29111%0D%0A111111111111%24111111111111)

**Details**:

- `(?<=\)[^(]*?)` - there must be `)` and then any 0+ chars other than `(`, as few as possible, before the current location
- `[^\s(/.;\p{L}\p{Nd}-]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespaces (`\s`), `(`, `.`, `;`, letters, digits and `-`
- `(?=[^(]*(?:\(|$))` - there must be `(` or end of string (`(?:\(|$)`) after 0+ chars other than `(` (see `[^(]*`) to the right of the current location.